# app crashes when on navigating to different activity

Tags: android, android-activity

I am trying to have my app navigate to another activity on a button click but whenever I do that the app simply crashes. I don't understand why this is happening.

My code in the `add.java` page which will handle the button click and navigate to the other class, `WifiConnections`

**Code in add.java**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.add);
    addListenerOnButton();

}

public void addListenerOnButton() {

final Context context = this;

Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.addb);

button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {

        Intent intent = new Intent(context, WifiConnections.class);
        startActivity(intent);

    }

});
```

}

However When I set the Wificonnections.xml to be the starting layout in the manifest file the wifi connections part works fine but on trying to navigate it crashes.

**Android Manifest**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.abhi.myapplication2">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".login"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:name=".WifiConnections" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:name=".add" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:name=".signup" >
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**WifiConnections Oncreate method**

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.wifi_connections);
        mainText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mainText);

        // Initiate wifi service manager
        mainWifi = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);

        // Check for wifi is disabled
        if (mainWifi.isWifiEnabled() == false)
        {
            // If wifi disabled then enable it
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "wifi is disabled..making it enabled",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            mainWifi.setWifiEnabled(true);
        }

        // wifi scaned value broadcast receiver
        receiverWifi = new WifiReceiver();

        // Register broadcast receiver
        // Broacast receiver will automatically call when number of wifi connections changed
        registerReceiver(receiverWifi, new IntentFilter(WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION));
        mainWifi.startScan();
        mainText.setText("Starting Scan...");
    }
```

**Code for add.xml**

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true">
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/layout_add">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/addb"
        style="@android:style/Widget.Material.Button.Borderless"
        android:background="@drawable/add"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="110dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="100dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="60dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="170dp"
        android:onClick="addclick"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="No device added"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="130dp"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Click to add device"
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:textSize="20sp" />
</RelativeLayout>
    </ScrollView>
```

**The complete project**
http://www37.zippyshare.com/v/10112230/file.html

**LogCat here :**

```
12-25 09:28:10.460 1952-1952/android.techbreeze.in W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with   uncaught exception (group=0xb0ec4648) 
12-25 09:28:10.470 1952-1952/android.techbreeze.in E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main 
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find a method addclick(View) in the activity class   com.example.abhi.myapplication2.login for onClick handler on view class android.widget.Button with id    'addb' 
at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3620) 
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4240) 
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17721) 
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553) 
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
 Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: addclick [class android.view.View] 
at java.lang.Class.getConstructorOrMethod(Class.java:423) 
 at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:787) 
at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3613) 
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4240) 
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17721) 
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553) 
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: add your `logcat` error

Comment: Put your logcat (or just look for the stacktrace yourself). You likely have a NULL pointer from not initializing a view.

Comment: There is no simple crash. Post the logcat please.

Comment: the issue is i am on an amd machine and emulators just dont work i m running it in my phn. Any ways to get the error occuring to be displayed on crash?

Comment: you defined the WifiConnections activity in manifest?

Comment: added manifest @LiranPeretz

Comment: Show WifiConnections code

Comment: you don't have the error log? you can post WifiConnections onCreate method?

Comment: @LiranPeretz added the onCreate method

Comment: it's really difficult to know why this activity crash without log, i suggest that you check if mainWifi == null

Comment: @LiranPeretz if I send u the project in a zip file could you run it on an emulator and help me out? I am really in a big trouble not having an working emulator is making it very difficult for me to debug :(

Comment: could you post your `add.xml`

Comment: try genimotion emulator, if this not help u let me know and i try to help u with running the project and getting this error

Comment: @LiranPeretz I just added the logcat with the help from Darkie. The issue seems to be that the app is looking in the login.java file for onlick event for the button with the id addb button in the add.xml file.

Answer (score 1):

Remove these line,

```
style="@android:style/Widget.Material.Button.Borderless"
android:onClick="addclick"
```

under the Button tag in `add.xml`

Comment: Done, still crashes must be new errors this time have no idea what they are so ... :(

Answer (score 1):

remove android:onClick="addclick" from "addb" button

Comment: made the change but app still crashes @Liran Peretz could you maybe download the whole project file and try it out yourself?

Comment: for you... anything :)

Comment: @RickRoy, if you have removed the specified lines, you should be getting a new error. Could you update that logcat error

Comment: i cant run the project i got an error: A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:_debugCompile'.
   > Could not find com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3.
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/21.0.3/appcompat-v7-21.0.3.pom
         https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/21.0.3/appcompat-v7-21.0.3.jar
     Required by:
         LED:app:unspecified

Comment: @codePG I have no way to get the logcat, I am on a AMD machine running a linux distro, Chakra OS, so nope can't post the new logcat unless Draike or some1 in here posts it for me :(

Comment: @LiranPeretz ty for the try though, this is so painful :(

Answer (score 0):

I see two ways of solving this problem.
First: initialize your Context variable right in the onCreate method, like this:

```
public class SomeActivity extends Activity{
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.add);
    addListenerOnButton();
    contex = this;
    }
...
}
```

Second: do the same, still use not `this` but the following:

```
contex = getApplicationContext();
```

because Intents like usage of application context very much.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(Add.this, WifiConnections.class);
```

and also remove the

```
final Context context = this;
```

Hope it helps ... :)

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, tried but same results. App crashes

Comment: @RickRoy post logcat so that we have a clear view what is the problem ... :)

Comment: That is the big trouble I am on an AMD based linux OS :( No emulator works how will I post the logcat :( If I send u the .zip of the whole project will you be kind enough to at least post the error in here so that I can understand what is actually going on?

Comment: @RickRoy ok send me the .zip file ...ASAP

Comment: @RickRoy what is the login password ? :D

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67670/discussion-between-rick-roy-and-darkie).